# Gitlab CI - exposing port/service of spawned docker container

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, nginx-ingress

I have setup a testplant of Gitlab CI

- Gitlab-CE on ubuntu 18.04 VM
- Docker gitlab runner
- Microk8s cluster
- I am able to install the gitlab managed Ingress controller

As I am running dind, how should I expose port 4000 to my host machine (VM) and what is the best way to do it ?

- I tried to play around with gitlab installed ingress controller, but not sure where the config files/yaml for gitlab managed apps ?
- Tried simple nodeport `expose` and it did not help

```
kubectl -n gitlab-managed-apps expose deployment <Gitlab Runner> --type=NodePort --port=4000
```

Below is my `gitlab-ci.yaml` file..

```yaml
image: docker:19.03.13

services:
  - name: docker:18.09.7-dind
    command:
      [
        '--insecure-registry=gitlab.local:32000',
      ]

stages:
  - testing

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE: img1

before_script:
  - echo "$REG_PASSWORD" | docker -D login "$CI_REGISTRY" -u "$REG_USER" --password-stdin

testing:
  stage: testing
  tags: [docker]
  script:
    - docker pull "gitlab.local:32000/$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"
    - docker images
    - hostname
    - docker run --rm -d -p 4000:4000 "gitlab.local:32000/$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"
    - netstat -na | grep -w 4000
    - sleep 3600
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out what was the issue on exposing using k8s services. It was the selector that was not clearly defined. Some key points to note

1. I could see that the port was listening on IPv6 interface (::4000) within the pod. However this was not the problem
2. I added podLabels in config.toml of the gitlab runner config (e.g. app: myapp). This way, each pod spawned by the runner had a predefined label
3. Used the label in my selector section of the LB service

Hope its useful to anyone